# How do I get the field definition of a paragraphs image field

Tags: 8, nodes, paragraphs

I need to get the resolution of the image using `getFieldDefinitions()`. For normal fields I can get the field definitions with below.

```
$fieldDefinition = \Drupal::entityManager()->getFieldDefinitions('node', $type);
foreach ($fieldDefinition as $field_name => $field_definition) {
    $settings    = $field_definition->getSettings();
    $resolution  = $settings['min_resolution'];
}
```

How do I get the field definition of a image field inside of a paragraphs field.

Comment: change 'node' to 'paragraph'.

Answer (score 0):

As it mention in comment just use `paragraph` instead of `node`.

```
$fieldDefinition = \Drupal::entityManager()->getFieldDefinitions('paragraph', 'your_paragraph_type_name');
    foreach ($fieldDefinition as $field_name => $field_definition) {
      if ($field_definition->getType() == 'image'){
        $settings    = $field_definition->getSettings();
        $resolution  = $settings['min_resolution'];
      }
    }
```